# Is there any way to put a space between text in a Facebook status?

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to put a space between paragraphs in a Facebook status?
I try shift and enter, but it appears that only works for Facebook comments, not Facebook business pages.
I circled in blue where I want spaces instead of using "---"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds silly, but have you tried simply pressing enter?

I just done this on the web app (with Facebook's native dark theme enabled) in Chrome with a EN-UK keyboard and it worked.

I have never had any issues with carriage returns on Facebook status in the mobile and desktop web-app or the android app.

[image: Example using the enter key:]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tedious, but I press enter, then on the new row I paste in a blank "space"/"character" (I don't think it works with the ordinary space). I normally have one saved on my notes pad, but when I need it I pick it up in Word/Insert Symbol/More Symbols where I select character cod 034F (the code can be typed into the box in the box in the bottom right corner and then the right character is selected). I copy the selected character and past into the blank row in FB.

Comment: Hi Christina, can you confirm that the answer  provided by  @TheJulyPlot in 2020 [simply press enter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/142738/197518) does not work.